# Assigning value to array element in assembly (GAS syntax)

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att

I have the following C code that returns 9:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[4]={0};
    array[2]=9;
    return array[2];
}
```

To accomplish the same in assembly language I have tried:

```
.section .data
array: .zero 4    
.section .text
    .globl _start
_start:
    mov $2,%esi
    mov array(,%esi,4),%ecx   # copy address of array[2] to %ecx
    mov $9,%ecx
    mov $1,%eax
    mov array(,%esi,4),%ebx   # return the value of array[2]
    int $0x80
```

assembled and linked with:

```
gcc -g -c array.s && ld array.o && ./a.out
```

However this program returns `0` instead of `9`:

```
>./a.out
>echo $?
0
```

I suspect the problem is in the lines with comments. After various unsuccessful attempts to find the problem I decided to ask the question: How to change of the value an array element (in this case `array[2]`) in assembly?

Comment: `mov array(,%esi,4),%ecx   # copy address of array[2] to %ecx` - this loads value from memory. To get address in similar way one can use `lea array(,%esi,4),%ecx`. And `mov $9,%ecx` loads value 9 into `ecx`, it does not involve any extra memory access except the instruction opcode itself. And your final `mov array(,%esi,4),%ebx` is completely correct and doing what it should, but if you will check how it differs from that "move address to ecx", there's no difference, so I'm not sure why you expect different result. (also using debugger to watch CPU state per instruction is of tremendous help)

Comment: And to modify array in fixed way, you can skip all those extra preparations, and just do immediately `movl $9, array+2*4` to use the [`MOV r/m32, imm32` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) to write immediate directly into memory. If you insist on indexing (to learn it for later), then `movl $9, array(,%esi,4)` writes value 9 into memory at "array + esi*4". To use "address" in `ecx` (if it would hold one), you can do `movl $9,(%ecx)`, to write into memory, the parentheses make it memory operand, not register, as target.

Comment: Thanks, now I see the flaws with the code I posted. Both `movl $9, array+2*4` and `movl $9,array(,%esi,4)` give the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.section .data
array: .zero 16               # allocate 16 bytes instead of 4
.section .text
    .globl _start
_start:
    mov $2,%esi
    lea array(,%esi,4),%ecx   # copy address of array[2] to %ecx, not the value
    mov $9, %ebx
    mov %ebx,(%ecx)             # assign value into the memory pointed by %ecx
    mov $1,%eax
    mov array(,%esi,4),%ebx
    int $0x80
```

Comment: The line `mov $9,(%ecx)` gives the error: `no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands;`

Comment: Put the value in a register (`%ebx`) before moving it in memory, or just add `l` suffix to the mnemonic: `movl $9, (%ecx)`

Comment: `mov $9,(%ecx)` is ambiguous, the assembler doesn't know if byte, word or dword should be written in memory (all three options are possible in x86 32 bit mode). The AT&T syntax is mostly used with suffix form of instructions like `movl / movw / movb /...`, but as long as there's no ambiguity, the `gas` will accept also missing suffix, like OP original code has everywhere. Writing suffix form everywhere is a bit more writing (and I personally have harder time to read it), but it may help to catch some bugs, like you want to store word into memory, and you write `movw %eax,(%ebp)` = `eax` error.